# OpenSSL::Cipher::Ciphererror on Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to deploy my rails 7 app using capistrano to aws EC2 instance. When I run `cap production deploy`, my deployment failed with this errors:

[image]

Here is my `Capfile`:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"
require "capistrano/puma"
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

My `config/deploy.rb`

```
# Change these
server '18.219.86.131', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:vuongtr01/senior_project.git'
set :application,     'wolfpack'

set :rbenv_type, :user 
set :rbenv_ruby,      '3.2.2'
# set :rbenv_ruby_dir,  '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2'
# set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
# set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
# set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value

# If using Digital Ocean's Ruby on Rails Marketplace framework, your username is 'rails'
set :user,            'ubuntu'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}/"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :puma_systemctl_user, :system

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :main
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
set :linked_files, %w(config/master.key)
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before 'deploy:starting', 'puma:make_dirs'
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do

      # Update this to your branch name: master, main, etc. Here it's main
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/main`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/main"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        invoke 'puma:restart'
      end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  # after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

My `config/deploy/production.rb`

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, :production
set :migration_role, :app
set :migration_command, 'db:migrate'
set :branch, "main"
```

In my server, I add `RAILS_MASTER_KEY="key_in_master.key_file"` to `/etc/environment`.

I tried to fix by following this [instruction](https://myrtana.sk/articles/howto-fix-rails-7-openssl-cipher-error). but it still does not work. Here is what I did:

1. Delete `RAILS_MASTER_KEY="key_in_master.key_file"` in `/etc/environment` and copy `master.key` file to `/home/ubuntu/apps/wolfpack/shared/config`
2. delete `config/credentials.yml.enc`, `master.key` files, then re-created new credentials `EDITOR=vim bin/rails credentials:edit`. Then repeated step 1.